# Verifying ownership of utxos

Tags: transactions, validation

Is there any other way besides signing a transaction to verify ownership of utxos?

Answer (score 3):

To 'own some bitcoins' is to own the private key that allows a UTXO to be spent, so your question can be refined to "*how do you verify ownership of a private key that controls a UTXO?"*

There are a few ways you could do this:

- Sign a generic message with the key, such as *"I am the owner of bitcoin address 1a5Ag23...."*
- Sign a transaction with the key, spending the coins to a new address (you could post the address prior to broadcasting the tx, to prove the coins are not just moving by coincidence)
- You could show off the private key itself (but this is a very bad idea! The bitcoins probably would not remain yours for long...)

Comment: I disagree that owning BTC is equal to having access to private keys. Coinbase certainly does not own all the BTC they have keys for, for example.

Comment: @PieterWuille I guess it is helpful to differentiate between 'ownership according to the blockchain' and 'ownership according to legal/social contracts'. In any case, the UTXOs  Coinbase controls would not map perfectly onto user account balances, so we can't really point to a specific CoinBase-controlled UTXO and say *"that one belongs to user x"*. Coinbase may be reputable and have intent to fulfill their duties as a custodial service, but sketchy exchanges that have exit scammed in the past help prove my point. If someone owes you $5 but hasn't paid it back, you don't own that $5. They do.

Comment: In this sense, perhaps it would be better to say 'Control of the UTXO', rather than 'Ownership of the UTXO'. I think that satisfies both of our arguments.

Comment: I think there's a difference between money owed (a debt) and custodial control. Even the sketchiest exchange doesn't own your money - you're perhaps making a bad business decision to risk having them control it, but it in no way makes the money owned by them. I think ownership is inherently a social construct, and not something described by the blockchain. The latter is just a way to reduce risk of having the wrong parties take control. It's even more complicated with UTXOs controlled by escrow or hashlocked contracts. These don't have a clear identifiable owner key even.

Comment: Nonetheless, the answer does not delve into ownership of BTC. Coinbase certainly has ownership of the private keys needed to sign for each utxo.